# Xpath extract extract value from content

Tags: selenium, xpath

I want my selenium webdriver to extract value 170

XPath

```
//*[contains(@class, '_wtiln _bdn9q _9a071_2MEB_')]/text()[1]
```

Result what is this xpath selecting
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCX2B.png)

The error what i get:

```
InvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression is [object Text]. It should be an element
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//div[@itemprop='offers' and @itemtype='http://schema.org/Offer']/meta/@content
```

The result should be `170.00`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//*[contains(@class, '_9a071_1LGgN')]/div[1]/meta[1]/@content/text()
```